# Flutter Read Realtime Database

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, count

I'm trying to count the number of messages in my Firebase Realtime Database but I can't read further than the first 'messages' branch.

I use this command to display the exact number of conversations I've created.

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('messages').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
  print(snapshot.value.length);
});
```

He looks good to me 14 but I need to do a count of each message created in each branch (chat room).

To understand the tree structure:

messages
   ----------id chat room
              -------------id message

[image: database]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the `onChildAdded` stream. This stream is called with each child node of the location on which you listen, so one level lower in the JSON tree.

It would look something like:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('messages').onChildAdded.listen((Event event) {
    print(event.snapshot.value.length);
});
```

When you first call `onChildAdded.listen`, the length for each existing child node will be printed. Then afterwards, if you add a new child node (directly) under `messages`, the length of that will be printed too.

Comment: From a data download and hence cost perspective is it more efficient/better practice  to maintain a message count on the messages-chat room node?

Comment: The code above is downloading everything under `messages`. If all you need is a count of the child nodes, this is incredibly wasteful. If that is all you'll do with the downloads, it'd indeed be better to keep a count.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. That is what I thought and have implemented.